# Need help using Linq to transform a list into a different list

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have a list that contains 1 record:

```
[
  {
    "AccountNumber": 1234,
    "eDocConfirms": true,
    "eDocStatements": true,
    "eDocTaxforms": false
  }
]
```

This list is a strongly typed object with these properties:

```
        public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public bool? eDocConfirms { get; set; }
        public bool? eDocStatements { get; set; }
        public bool? eDocTaxforms { get; set; }
```

Using LINQ, I'd like to turn it into a list that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "AccountNumber": 1234,
    "EDocumentTypeName ": "Confirms"
  },
  {
    "AccountNumber": 1234,
    "EDocumentTypeName": "Statements"
  }
]
```

This new list will a list of a different type:

```
public class DeliveryPreference
    {
        public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public string EDocumentTypeName { get; set; }
    }
```

Note that Taxforms was not included in the new list because it was set to false in the first list.

I know I could easily do this with some loops, but I would prefer using LINQ.

I understand that Stack Overflow prefers that I show what I have tried, but I am having trouble wrapping my brain around this.

Comment: Any reason why Linq?

Comment: Is that a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`, or something else? If it's something else, can you post the definition of your "record"? It makes writing and testing a solution easier

Comment: You ask for a collection of some sort, but but what does the class in that collection look like?

Comment: Since you have one item and then get multiple, within the list, it should be SelectMany, and inside it you need select properties which are true and account number. But it is not clear here what is the format. If it was a dictionary then you could do something like this pseudocode: list.SelectMany(item => item.Where(kvp => kvp.Value is true).Select(kvp => {AccountNumber = item[AccountNumber], kvp.Key = kvp.Value}))

Comment: @ViktorArsanov I have updated my question. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this case I would use additional function

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetTrueProperties(Data t)
{
    if (t.eDocConfirms == true) yield return "Confirms";
    if (t.eDocStatements == true) yield return "Statements";
    if (t.eDocTaxForms == true) yield return "Tax";
}
```

simply because it is an object and not a dictionary; else you could dynamically select properties which are true(or you could use reflection, but I think it would be too much here, since you have strongly typed object).

then it would look like

```
var list = new List<Data> {
new Data
{
    AccountNumber = 1,
    eDocConfirms = true,
    eDocStatements = true,
    eDocTaxForms = false
}
};
list.SelectMany(item => GetTrueProperties(item).Select(p => new DeliveryPreference
{
    AccountNumber = item.AccountNumber,
    EDocumentTypeName = p
}));
```

Comment: This is brilliant! I haven't used the "yield" keyword or the SelectMany much. This is a great example of both. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is very ugly code, but it works. It should be easy to comprehend. Reflection can be extracted to a new function.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public class Account {
      public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public bool? eDocConfirms { get; set; }
        public bool? eDocStatements { get; set; }
        public bool? eDocTaxforms { get; set; }
    }

    public class DeliveryPreference
    {
        public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public string EDocumentTypeName { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var acc = new Account {
            AccountNumber = 10,
            eDocConfirms = true,
            eDocStatements = false,
            eDocTaxforms = true
        };

        var transformed = acc.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(bool?) 
                   && ((bool?)p.GetValue(acc)).HasValue
                  && ((bool?)p.GetValue(acc)).Value)
            .Select(p => new DeliveryPreference {
                AccountNumber = acc.AccountNumber,
                EDocumentTypeName = p.Name.Substring(4)
            });

        foreach (var t in transformed) {
            Console.WriteLine(t.AccountNumber);
            Console.WriteLine(t.EDocumentTypeName);
        }
    }
}
```